# How to select null values of sql table with phpMyDataGrid

Tags: php, mysql, null, where-clause

i used `phpMyDataGrid` [tool](http://www.gurusistemas.com/_guru/indexdatagrid.php?page=samples) for generate reports in my final year `php` project. how should i select null column with `phpMyDataGrid`? my table and code as follows.

```
vehicle_license 
6606621252 
5965565553 
NULL
6656771252 
NULL
5345565553
NULL
6609877252 
2345565553
4566521252 
5964564563

/* Define fields to show */
$objGrid -> FormatColumn("regno", "Registration No", 5, 2, 0, "130", "left");
$objGrid -> FormatColumn("availability", "Registration status", 2, 2, 0,"50", "left", "check:Unavailable:Registered");
$objGrid -> FormatColumn("officerid", "Officer", 5, 2, 0, "130", "left");
$objGrid -> FormatColumn("datetime", "Data & Time", 5, 2, 0, "180", "left", "time:dmy:/");
$objGrid -> orderby("datetime", "DESC");

/* Records can be filtered to comply with a pre-defined condition */
$objGrid -> where ("driving_license = NULL");  //not working
$objGrid -> where ("driving_license = 'NULL'");  //not working
$objGrid -> where ("driving_license = 'IS NULL'");  //not working
//<> operator for 'not equal' is working
```

Comment: Try `driving_license IS NULL`

Comment: yes correct..working..:) thanx

Comment: I don't know what database you are using but MySQL' handling with Null is quite easy. You can read more about it here. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/working-with-null.html

Answer (score 1):

```
where ("driving_license IS NULL");
```

or

```
where ("driving_license = '' ");
```